# How to use Regex to find a specific string between two special characters?

Tags: sql, regex, powershell

I`m currently migrating sql data between two forum systems (Woltlab Burning Board 2 -> MyBB 1.8).

I need to change the internal links from http://example.com/thread.php?threadid=XYZ
 to http://example.com/showthread.php?tid=ABC. Thread ID's will change between the two systems, so I'm not able to do a simple string replace.

I already catch all posts containing http://example.com/thread.php?threadid=. Now I need to get the unique ID into a variable. As the whole post-string can also contain external links (e.g. http://google.com) I cant just catch Numbers before.

I would like to catch the Thread-ID from this string http://example.com/thread.php?threadid=XYZ, which is part of a bigger string (Forum Post). I guess Regex could be used for this.

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: So you want the replace the URL?

Comment: In Powershell `"[URL]=http://example.com/thread.php?threadid=XYZ[/URL]" -match '(?<=threadid=)\S+(?=\[/URL])';$Matches`  ... of course you have to improve this regex depending on your special needs.  ;-)

Comment: In PHP something like this `if (preg_match('%\[URL\]=(?P<url>http://example\.com/thread\.php\?threadid=)(?P<id>[^[]+)\[/URL\]%', $link, $regs)) {
 $oldUrl = $regs['url'];
 $linkId = $regs['url'];
}`

Comment: @Olaf, thanks, already helping me out. Now I get results that look like these - "1810]hier" and "2639&threadview=0&hilight=&hilightuser=0&page=1]hier".... Especially the extra php parameters seem to be problematic, since they are random. And some offtopic, greetings to my cc colleagues in berlin, I'm engineer in kerpen ;)

Comment: Will the thread id always be a number?

Comment: @AdminOfThings, yes, ID's are always integer

Comment: $Post_with_link_WBB -match '(?<=threadid=)\S+(?=\])'  this catches the unique ID's when no extra php arguments are passed, is it possible to add "&" as second breakout point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell, the following will capture the thread ID:

```
$URI = "http://example.com/thread.php?threadid=2438&Query=GetSomething?2345"
$tid = ($URI | select-string -pattern "threadid=(\d+)").matches.groups.value[1]
$tid
```

If there is no thread id to be captured, the `$tid` assignment will throw an error.